# ¿Cómo instalar 'babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx' en un proyecto Laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

Buenas. Estoy usando Vue2.js en un proyecto con Laravel 5.5, y estoy intentando usar la sintaxis JSX en las funciones de renderización de componentes Vue.
He mirado por todas partes, pero no he encontrado ninguna forma de conseguirlo usando Laravel Mix, y no he sacado nada en claro buscando entre los archivos del mismo proyecto.

Este es el repositorio del plugin de Babel que quiero usar en mi proyecto: https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx

Answer (score 1):

Vale, sólo hacía falta seguir las instrucciones del mismo repositorio del plugin, Laravel Mix se puede dejar de lado en este caso.
Dentro de la carpeta del proyecto he ejecutado:

```
npm install babel-plugin-syntax-jsx babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props babel-preset-env --save-dev
```

Otra vez dentro de la carpeta he creado el archivo .babelrc con el contenido:

```
{
    "presets": ["env"],
    "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx"],
    "ignore": ["node_modules"]
}
```

La siguiente vez que ejecuté Laravel Mix (npm run dev), el código con sintaxis jsx compilaba bien, así que entiendo que esta es la solución.
He leído por ahí que la configuración que se especifica en el fichero .babelrc se combina con la configuración de Laravel Mix, por lo que en principio no tendría que haber ningún problema en este sentido.